# Visual Studio debugging execution path

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I have c code like.

```
FILE * fin = fopen("myfile", "rb");
if (fin == NULL)
{
    printf("file myfile does not exist, closing");
    return false;
}
```

It works when compiled, but not in debugging mode (stepping trough) where it return false.
checking argv[0] is ok and absolute paths are working both ways.

Comment: So absolute paths work both ways, but relative paths do not?  Check that your relative paths are constructed properly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you run the program in the debugger, you need to set the current working directory, in the project debug settings.

As pointed below by user Irhala A in Visual Studio 2017 the setting is found at "Project -> [ProjectName] Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Working Directory".

Comment: To anyone needing this, in VS2017, the setting is found at "Project -> [ProjectName] Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Working Directory". That configuration is saved in [ProjectName].vcxproj.user